# A sample of event attendees take both a pre and post event sentiment survey, how do I compare answers with population?

Tags: confidence-interval, sentiment-analysis

I am measuring the net change in opinion after an event. For example, if this is the question
"This university is a leader in academic research"
then the available answers are
"1) Completely disagree, 2) Somewhat disagree, 3) Neutral, 4) Somewhat agree, 5) Completely agree"

My sample is a set of attendees who took both a pre and post event survey (pre mandatory, post optional, so the intersection of these two). Lets say this sample is 2000 people, out of 14000 total attendees. If 78% of this sample responded with 4 or 5 before the event and then 84% of that same sample responded with 4 or 5 after the event (a 6% increase in agreement), what can I say about the net change for all the attendees? I'm looking for some way to express that the change in the sample is significant to the population, as well as give an estimate of what the change was for the population. Currently I'm splitting the data up into two buckets, Agreed (answer 4 or 5) and Disagreed (answer 1, 2, or 3), and looking for changes in the proportion of Agreed.

The first thing I tried was a 95% CI for proportions, but I'm concerned it's misleading and over simplifying. There's clearly a correlation, since the surveys came from the same attendees, and the sample could be bias. I have demographic information about each attendee and thought to compare the characteristics of the sample to the population, but I'm not sure where to begin there either.

Thank you!

Comment: you might offer some more details on why you want a confidence interval and the methods you suspect might work or have tried to date.

Comment: Edited to give a little more information. I need some kind of estimated change to the overall population, a confidence interval was the first thing that popped in my head.